# Which Load balancer between clients and Kong

Tags: dns, load-balancing, kong

Suppose I want to put in place this KONG architecture:

[image]

1) What do I need to use for the "Load Balancer"?

2) How I can ensure High Availability of the "Load Balancer" ? and how to make it fully transparent for the Clients (who must know only one @IP or FQDN)?

3) How the load balancer will find which Kong from the Kong's Cluster should process a Client request?

Any infos is welcomed ;-)

Seb

Comment: Hi, Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.10.x, Kong provides a built-in load balancer and upstream support. You can read more about it at https://getkong.org/docs/0.10.x/loadbalancing/#ring-balancer

Comment: That link looks like it covers load-balancing from Kong to the API, not from the client to multiple Kong instances?